# How do I get to the previous folder in path?

Tags: c

How do I tell the program to look for the folder in the previous directory?

I've tried writing "../assets/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf", but that doesn't work.

```
font = TTF_OpenFont ( "assets/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf", 24 );
```

My asset folder is not in the current directory but in the previous directory

Comment: Try /../assets/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf

Comment: @StrahinjaRodic, nope that doesn't work. It works with "assets/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf" and 'assets' folder being in the same diectory.

Comment: What do you mean by “previous directory”?  Does your program use `chdir()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In my parent directory I have a 'source' folder with .c files. Also this parent dir contains an 'assets' folder. I need my path from program(which is in 'source' folder) to go back in the parent dir and search for the 'assets' folder. No, I'm not using chdir().

Comment: Bit of terminology clarification might help. Unless you are using `chdir` or the like, there is no notion of 'previous directory'. It sounds like you mean 'parent directory', ie the directory which contains current directory. Calling this parent directory "p' (for example) , your program's current working direction is "p/source" you can open the files in "p/assets" by using the path (file name w/ directories) "../assets/filename" or "../assets/fonts/DejeVuSans.ttf"

Comment: @D'Nabre, The explanation you gave is correct. but ../ doesn't work for some reason unfortunately.

Comment: @suraj-nishad Looks like you're using SDL2_ttf to load a font. Not sure why the path isn't work. I'd copy the font to the CWD of the program and make sure that loads properly. This will isolate the issue to be the path for open or something else. The specific error you are getting from TTF_GetError() might be useful.

Comment: @SurajNishad this look like an oddity of SDL2_ttf not handling relative paths. Which is something that should get fixed. You'll need to use an absolute path to the font file for the moment. What platform/OS are you using? I'm going to look into the issue, a post a answer with details on it (along with a easy way to grab the absolute path in a situation like), but want to make sure it works seamlessly on whatever setup you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Short version (I'll try to expand later).

The library you're using SDL2_ttf's TTF_OpenFont requires an absolute path, not a relative one. This odd, because just about everywhere else an open will take a relative path ("../assests/fonts/DejeVuSans.ttf") not an absolute ("/home/me/Project/SDL2_thing/assets/fonts/DejeVuSans.ttf").

Assuming your program is running in a directory like "/home/me/Project/SDL2_thing/source/my_program". To get the parent directory (SDL2_thing) and build the absolute path, this snippet should work (based on POSIX functions and a bit sloppy with buffer sizes):

```
#include <stdio.h>   //printf
#include <unistd.h>  //getcwd
#include <libgen.h>  //dirname

int main() {

        char buffer[1024];
        char target[2048];

        //get the full path to the current working directory
        getcwd(buffer, 1024);
        printf("cwd\t: %s \n", buffer);
        // This will chop off the directory at the end of the path (doing ../source) effectively)
        dirname(buffer);
        printf("parent\t: %s \n", buffer);

        //Take the path we have ".../SDL2_thing" and build a string appending the rest
        sprintf(target, "%s/assets/fonts/DejeVuSans.ttf", buffer);
        printf("target\t: %s \n", target);

        return 0;
}
```

This is a complete program you can easily compile and run to see the outputs of intermediate value. Again, I'm just tossing around a couple big buffers which is sloppy and should be avoid. Use the proper MAX_PATH constants and such. You should be able to adapt this to get the absolute path to your font and give to TTF_OpenFont().

Check the result of the TTF_OpenFont() call. If null, print the string that TTF_GetError() gives you. This should help determine where the error is.

If you try this solution and have issues respond by commenting on this answer.

When I get a chance I'm going to look into why this function doesn't take an absolute and at least try to get it documented as such if not fixed.